# Delete characters in a string Python

Tags: python, string, replace, filepath

```
orig_string = "\\\\file_foo\\bar\\text-to-be-deleted\\foo-bar.pdf"
```

The original string needs to be modified (copy into a new variable) to look like the new_string below. The file has thousands of lines with the same format (file path of a pdf file).

```
new_string = "\\\\file_foo\\bar\\foo-bar.pdf"
```

How do I modify the orig_string to look like the new string?

**Edit:**
Sorry, I forgot to mention on my original post.  The '\text-to-be-deleted' is not the same. All filepath have different '\text-to-be-deleted' string.

Ex.

```
"\\\\file_foo\\bar\\path100\\foo-bar.pdf"
"\\\\file_foo\\bar\\path-sample\\foo-bar.pdf"
"\\\\file_foo\\bar\\another-text-be-deleted\\foo-bar.pdf"
```

...
and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a method. Hope it can help you.

```
orig_string = "\\\\file_foo\\bar\\text-to-be-deleted\\foo-bar.pdf"
back_index = orig_string.rfind('\\')
front_index = orig_string[:back_index].rfind('\\')
new_string = orig_string[:front_index] + orig_string[back_index:]
print(new_string)
```

**Output**

```
'\\\\file_foo\\bar\\foo-bar.pdf'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know what the `text-to-be-deleted` is, then you can use

```
new_string = orig_string.replace('text-to-be-deleted\\','')
```

If you only know the parts you want to keep, I would use [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) with the parts you know as arguments.

EDIT (split version):
I'd do this, but there might be cleaner out there:

```
orig_string = "\\\\file_foo\\bar\\text-to-be-deleted\\foo-bar.pdf"

temp_str = orig_string.split('\\')
idx = temp_str.index('bar')

new_string = temp_str[:idx+1] + temp_str[idx+2:]
new_string = '\\'.join(new_string)
print(new_string)#\\file_foo\bar\foo-bar.pdf
```

Comment: Are the parts to be located always located in the same point in the file-path (ie, the directory before the file-name)? Can we assume the `bar` directory is always going to appear before the part to be deleted?

Comment: yes, it is always in the same point before the filename (.pdf). I think the .split works.

Comment: Edited my answer for the split() method (just change 'bar' in line 3 to whatever you need), hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I am considering you want to remove 2nd last element of every path

```
orig_string = "\\\\file_foo\\bar\\text-to-be-deleted\\foo-bar.pdf"
orig_string = orig_string.split("\\")
value = orig_string[:-1]
str1 = orig_string[-1]
value[-1] = str1
value[0] = "\\"#Insert "\\" at index 0
value[1] = "\\"#Insert "\\" at index 1
print('\\'.join(value))#join the list
```

**Output**

```
\\\\file_foo\bar\foo-bar.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

use the following code:

```
orig_string = "\\\\file_foo\\bar\\text-to-be-deleted\\foo-bar.pdf"
new_string = orig_string
start = new_string.find("bar\\")
start = start + 4 # so the start points to char next to bar\\
end = new_string.find("\\foo")
temp = new_string[start:end] # this the text to be deleted
new_string = new_string.replace(temp , "") #this is the required final string
```

output:

```
\\file_foo\bar\\foo-bar.pdf
```

Comment: you can add '\\' before the output in same way as mentioned 1st answer :)